# How would I sort this Dictionary by value then if the same sort it by key value?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
# Imports the sys library
import sys
# Returns the file's contents
def readFile():
    return open("gettysburg.txt", "r").read()
# Writes to the file with the variable output
def writeFile(output):
    open("out.out", "w").write(output)
# Returns all of the words of the variable content by splitting the string by the space
def getWords(content):
    return content.replace("--", " ").replace("\n", " ").replace(".", "").replace("!", "").replace(",", "").replace("?", "").split(" ")
def main():
    # Initiates a HashMap
    wordCounts = dict()
    for text in getWords(readFile()):
        # Checks if the string is empty
        if (text != ""):
            # If the text is not in variable wordCounts then add it to the wordCounts makes it = 1 else then increment it by 1
            if (not text in wordCounts):
                wordCounts[text] = 1
            else:
                wordCounts[text] = wordCounts[text] + 1
    print(wordCounts)
    for i in range(0, 9):
        print(sorted(wordCounts, key=wordCounts.__getitem__, reverse=True)[i])
main()
```

How would I sort wordCounts by value then sort it by key?

I cannot use any sort of libraries so please do not suggest any use of libraries to improve efficiency.

I'm kind of stumped on this one.

Just some insight on what I'm doing:

Basically I'm finding the word frequency with a block of text and printing it out alphabetically based on value.

Comment: It's a class assignment thus I have to comment in what each line does.

Comment: Your comments should really explain the algorithm to someone who is fluent in python, you'll probably get marked down for a comment like "initiate a HashMap" as the next line says the exact same thing but in python not english. Instead of single comments per line I personally prefer a longer description at the top of each function stating what it does, how and what it requires as inputs and what it returns.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll fix that. Though this has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Since this is for class I won't just jump straight in with a full answer. If your sort keys are tuples, it will sort by the first item in the tuple first, then break ties with the second item. So if you make your key function return tuples...

Comment: @Marius I'm trying, though I'm still having the same issue.
print(sorted([(value, key) for key, value in wordCounts.items()], reverse=True))

Comment: if you use python 3 dict.items() doesn't return a list of tuples, it returns a dict_items object and it doesn't sort well, you need to pass the result in the list constructor `list(dict.items())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the output you are looking for?

```
d = dict()

d['that']= 13
d['the']=9
d['to']=8
d['we']=8
d['here']=8
d['a']=7
d['and']=6
d['nation']=5
d['not']=5
d['for']=5
d['can']=5
d['of']=5
d['have']=5

ordered = dict()
for e in d:
  if d[e] not in ordered:
    ordered[d[e]] = []
  ordered[d[e]].append(e)

for e in reversed(sorted(ordered.keys())):
  for v in sorted(ordered[e]):
    print e, v
```

Outputs:

```
13 that
9 the
8 here
8 to
8 we
7 a
6 and
5 can
5 for
5 have
5 nation
5 not
5 of
```

Comment: I can't use libraries as stated in the problem itself.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "I can't import other libraries."

Comment: EDIT: Does not use OrderedDict anymore.

Comment: It's still not sorting it correctly for some reason....[('that', 13), ('the', 9), ('to', 8), ('we', 8), ('here', 8), ('a', 7), ('and', 6), ('nation', 5), ('not', 5), ('for', 5), ('can', 5), ('of', 5), ('have', 5)]

Comment: The output should be "that, the, here, to, we, a, and, can, for, have"

Answer (score 1):

```
d = dict()
d["a"] = 10
d["ab"] = 8
d["abc"] = 10
d["bc"] = 9

for value, key in sorted(zip(d.values(), d.keys())):
    print(value, key)
```

output :

```
8 ab
9 bc
10 a
10 abc
```